# How to set drop target on high density display

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, draggable, retina-display, gojs

I am working on a code base that uses GoJS.  On a high display density display, such as a macbook pro with retina display, the drop detection is off, but on a normal display the dragover and drop detection is correct.

Is there a setting or way to configure GoJS to get the correct dragover and drop detection on a diagram?

Comment: What version of GoJS are you using?